# Select multiple with and in one column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
article_id cat_id
        70      7
        70      8
        71      9
        71      8
```

I need `article_id` where `cat_id=8` and `cat_id=7` and the result must return 70.

I tried this code but neither worked:

```
SELECT * 
FROM andishkadeh_article_catgory 
WHERE cat_id=6 AND cat_id=8

SELECT * 
FROM andishkadeh_article_catgory 
WHERE cat_id in (6,8)
```

Comment: Surely, you can see why a value can't be equal to 6 **and** 8 at the same time

Comment: I think I get what you want, but in your sample data, article_id 70 doesn't have cat_id 8 and 6

Comment: Please post examples of data as **plain-text** whenever possible. External screenshots are annoying and cannot be used as sample data for answers.

Comment: `SELECT article_id FROM my_table WHERE cat_id IN (7,8) GROUP BY article_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;` and note that article_catgory_id is redundant, so I removed it. Your PRIMARY KEY would be formed on `(article_id,cat_id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I understood the question. If you need to find the `article_id` that has **2 different rows** with values for `cat_id` of 7 and 8, then you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT article_id 
FROM andishkadeh_article_catgory a
WHERE cat_id = 7
AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM andishkadeh_article_catgory
           WHERE cat_id = 8
           AND article_id = a.article_id)
```

Comment: its work, but its depend to my category, for example if i insert new article_id with cat_id 8 than what i must to do

Comment: @Buddha I don't know, what do you want to happen if you insert a new article_id with cat_id 8?, if that same article_id doesn't also have a cat_id of 7, it won't be in the result

Comment: i want to filter my article depended to my category_id

Comment: @Buddha look, this does what you wanted, if you want something else, then you can ask another question or at least clarify this one

Comment: DISTINCT is surely redundant.